# Is there any BP node that provides full history per account for a given token contract?

Tags: eosio.token

Does any block producers currently provide public access API node with full history for each EOS account for any token contracts?

I want to fetch all transaction data for any EOS account for any token contract to build a tax-centric CSV/Google spreadsheet app to save EOS account holders from the hassle of creating/maintaining manual spreadsheets for tax and other accounting purposes. Sort of my EOSMINT project.

Running my own node on AWS or Linode cloud with history plugin + mongo set up is a route but it seems to me that block producers have better infrastructure and can offer this readily.  Yet, I cannot find one yet.

The EOSInfra.io project folks told me that they offer full history but for a limited time range. This won't work.

Comment: have you tried the atticlabs node?

Comment: eoscanada, eossweden, meet.one and eosdac (not sure if they disabled history-plugin in the meantime) also provide full history. 

If you want to consume that huge amount of transactions I would use one of the websocket-apis. https://www.dfuse.io/en or https://eospark.com/openapi. Both have full history.

Answer (score 1):

The only useful solution I found so far is the API proxy provided by https://proxy.eosnode.tools.

It allows me to grab actions in chunks like 0-300, 300-500, etc. which should work for me since I am running a batch process per account to keep data localized.

Comment: Full history is expensive and thus you need to collect your own (partial) history and store it offchain locally. As an unrelated task, I am building Python tooling to have a "cap table at any point of time" for a token. EOS support will come the second half of this year. https://docs.tokenmarket.net/erc-20-holders.html